Processing the image when it got uploaded from admin site
I want to upload some transparent background png through the django admin site. But around the uploading I wish to processing them like making the background to be black.
I have a class from models.py like this:
class AllClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, help_text="Name of this class(e.g. Wardancer)")
    archetype = models.ForeignKey('Archetype', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='icons',default='media/default/default_icon.jpg')

A function like this should be called during or after the uploading:
def recolor(url):
    image = Image.open(url).convert("RGBA")
    new_image = Image.new("RGBA", image.size, "BLACK")
    new_image.paste(image, mask=image)

    return new_image.convert("RGB")

I tried this approach by adding it into my models.py file:
@receiver(post_save, sender=Image)
def crop_image(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    imgage = instance.image
    original = Image.open(imgage.src.path).convert("RGBA")
    new_image = Image.new("RGBA", original.size, "BLACK")
    new_image.paste(original, mask=original)
    instance.image = new_image

It did not work maybe I did not do it the right way.
To conclude, I want the image to be processed and preferably replaced with the processed image before the url got stored into the database

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
